# how to display a password error message when a user login

Tags: css, woocommerce

I want to hide the product can not be added to the cart,

I added this code in CSS to hide product error messages that can't be added to the basket, it works

```
.woocommerce-error {
display: none;  
}
```

after I added the code, the passwod error message was also hidden,

I don't want the passwod error message to be hidden,

please help me to display a passwod error when a user login.
thank you

Comment: You need to make the css selector more specific. If you show us the HTML surrounding both the basket error message and login error message we can help you make it more specific.

Comment: You may wanna share more code cuz it's hard to help with only that info

Comment: Why don't you just unpublish that product using WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the product element & error message in a container, and hide the element instead of hiding the whole thing.

Comment: Please explain how it is relevant to his question. This might make it more complex for him while he just needs to make his selector more specific.

Comment: Sorry misinterpreted the question, Answer changed